# Having Angular Migrate TSLint to ESLint Banana-In-Box Error

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint, codelyzer

I'm running into significant issues with my migration from TSLint to ESLint for my Angular project.  The way I'm working is I'm creating a brand new project (currently in Angular 9), and then I upgrade to Angular 10.2.  I have followed the guidelines in [@angular-eslint/schematic process](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-from-codelyzer-and-tslint), and I have run the npx tslint-to-eslint-config.  However, when I try to run ESLint via my Visual Studio Code extension, I get the following error as it tries to ESLint my app.component.ts file:

```
Error while loading rule '@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box': You have used a rule which requires '@angular-eslint/template-parser' to be used as the 'parser' in your ESLint config.
```

The following is my .eslintrc.js file configuration:

```
module.exports = {
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
},
"extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking"
],
"ignorePatterns": ["node_modules/**/*", "**/node_modules/**/*", "dist/**/*"],
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-import",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "@typescript-eslint/tslint"
],
"rules": {
  ...
  "@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box": "error",
  ...
},
root: true,
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*.ts"],
    "parserOptions": {
      "project": [
        "tsconfig.*?.json",
        "e2e/tsconfig.json"
      ],
      "createDefaultProgram": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
        "error", { "type": "element", "prefix": "app", "style": "kebab-case" }
      ],
      "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
        "error", { "type": "attribute", "prefix": "app", "style": "camelCase" }
      ],
      "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
        "off", { "accessibility": "explicit" }
      ],
      "arrow-parens": [
        "off",
        "always"
      ],
      "import/order": "off"
    }
  },
  {
    "files": [
      "*.html"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {}
  },
  {
    "files": ["*.component.html"],
    "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
    "rules": {
      "max-len": ["error", { "code": 200 }]
    }
  },
  {
    "files": ["*.component.ts"],
    "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"]
  }
]};
```

Every time I try to add that template as an extension, it gives me another error.  The only thing that stops the error is if I comment that rule out.  Can someone help me figure out how to get this rule to work and eliminate this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESLint error when trying to lint Angular templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361645/eslint-error-when-trying-to-lint-angular-templates)

Comment: The help instructions here might be useful: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/issues/948

Answer (score 6):

Replacing the section `parser` did the trick for me:

---

Your config:

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

Should replace with

```
"parser": "@angular-eslint/template-parser",
```