# What means 'Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.' error in IntelliJ IDEs family?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, intellij-idea, eslint

When I open `.vue` file, below error appears in my IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: XX\XX\CurrentFile.vue.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

[image]

Of course I will be glad if you teach me the solution, but first what I know what it means and WHY it appears.

I suspect that it is a some kind of bug, or inaccurate error message. Experimentally known what:

1. Sometimes it appears, sometimes - no.
2. It always appears when update eslint.
3. If to run `eslint` from console for some `.vue` file, eslint will finish the execution correctly. So seems like it is no eslint bug.

My Eslint config (YAML):

```yaml
parser: vue-eslint-parser
parserOptions:
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
  sourceType: module
  project: tsconfig.json
  tsconfigRootDir: ./
  extraFileExtensions: [ ".vue" ]

env:
  es6: true
  browser: true
  node: true

plugins:
  - "@typescript-eslint"
  - vue


rules:
  // ...
```

TypeScript settings:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2017",

    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "sourceMap": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve", // Limitation of the transpileOnly mode from ts-loader for .vue files.

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to a GitHub repo that exhibits the problem?

Comment: if you can't share all of the code as mentioned above, could you add in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @tomdaly I added TypeScript config to my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add your files to the `include` array in your tsconfig:

```
"include": [
  "path/to/src/**/*"
]
```

Source: [Github](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/967) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser)

Comment: Thank you for the solution! But please, tell me: 1) Why error does not refer to `include` array? 2) Why typescript config affecting to @typescrit-eslint?

Comment: `The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided` => It doesn't talk about the `include` array specifically but it states clearly that the error refers to inclusion

Comment: Typescript config affects `typescript-eslint` because the linter may parse differently based on the configuration. For example, if a file is not included in the tsconfig, typescript-eslint does not know if it should be parsed as typescript

Comment: O'K, the question has exhausted. Thank you very much for contributing to this article.

Comment: And if the files are included, and this error only seems to happen when adding new files?