# ESLint doesn't believe that I've included .vue files in my tsconfig

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I've got a Vue.js 2 project I'm working to port to TypeScript (a little at a time). I'm trying to get ESLint to parse my TypeScript files and Vue components, but when I run `vue-cli-service lint` all of my .vue files report this error:

```
error: Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/path/to/Foo.vue.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided
```

Of course, .vue files surely *are* included in my tsconfig.json file, as shown:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest", "node", "googlemaps"],
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/typings", "./src"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "functions",
    "scripts",
    "coverage",
    "__snapshots__",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "tests/**"
  ]
}
```

My ESLint config is set up like so:

```
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended",
    "prettier/vue",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "@vue/typescript",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],

  env: {
    browser: true,
    amd: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true
  },

  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "vue"],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
    extraFileExtensions: [".vue"]
  },

  rules: {
    "vue/component-name-in-template-casing": ["error", "PascalCase"],
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "warn",
    "no-async-promise-executor": "off",
    semi: "error",
    "jest/expect-expect": "off",
    "jest/no-try-expect": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/require-await": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "warn"
  },

  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.test.{j,t}s?(x)"],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I have a .eslintignore file with these entries:

```
/tests
.eslintrc.js
sw.js
*.config.js
*-config.js
```

I'm also running the following relevant plugins:

```
// package.json
...
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.2.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.2.0",
  "@vue/cli": "^4.5.4",
  "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.1.0",
  "eslint": "^7.9.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-beta.4",
...
```

I've tried nearly everything I know to do, aside from what I've got now (see above):

- Changing my tsconfig includes to `["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue"]`
- [Changing my tsconfig includes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011921) to just `"src/**/*"`
- Changing how I point ESLint to the tsconfig:

  - `"tsconfig.json"`
  - `path.resolve(__dirname, "./tsconfig.json")`
- Extending `@vue/typescript/recommended` rules *instead of* `@vue/typescript`
- Extending `@vue/typescript/recommended` rules *after* `@vue/typescript`
- Extending *no* `@vue` ESLint rules
- Excluding `es6: true` from the `env` entry in .eslintrc.js
- Omitting `plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "vue"]`

... each with identical results.

As you can see, I've listed `@typescript-eslint/parser` as a custom parser, as per [this Vue doc](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-a-custom-parser).

[This typescript-eslint issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2127) doesn't seem to apply, because the issue is in the CLI, not in VSCode. Also, this isn't just "new" .vue files, but *all* .vue files in the project.

Is ESLint correct that I've misconfigured something? How can I get it to lint my SFC components properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a [solution-style tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#support-for-solution-style-tsconfigjson-files) instead and using [eslintrc overrides](https://eslint.org/docs/5.0.0/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration) to select specific file extensions and point ESLint to the correct config.

Apply cleverly.