# Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation'

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint-staged

Today I run eslint，two script

```
 "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
 "eslint": "eslint --ext .tsx,.ts --fix ./src -c .eslintrc.js",
```

When I run `npm run eslint` // it's ok
When I run `npm run lint-staged` // it's wrong

lint-staged's result ;

```
> lint-staged
  ❯ Running tasks for src/**/*.tsx
    ✖ eslint --fix [FAILED]
    ◼ git add
  
✖ eslint --fix :


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.10.0

Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
Occurred while linting /Users/***/components/BrowserInfo/Index.tsx
    at Object.getParserServices (/Users/fugang/workspace/xinao/channel-desk/node_modules/_@typescript-eslint_experimental-utils@4.3.0@@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils/dist/eslint-utils/getParserServices.js:26:15)
```

In package lint-staged

What happend?

```
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.tsx": [
      "eslint --fix -c .eslintrc.js",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 210):

You have to add the following config to your .eslint.json file

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        ...
        "project": ["path/to/your/tsconfig/file"]
        ...
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Jovanović. In my project, I have added like below, as "tsconfig.json" and ".eslintrc.json" are at same level.                                                            
"parserOptions": {
      "project": ["tsconfig.json"]
  }

Comment: @RamyaVelivala did you ever figure out your issue? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: This answered looked promising and resolved that error but resulted in this new Eslint error at the top of the `.eslintrc.js` file itself: `Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.` https://stackoverflow.com/q/58510287/470749 seems related, but I haven't gotten any of those answers to work.

Comment: This should be your '.eslintrc.js' file, but the answer still applies.

Comment: Its very interesting that official site says to add <project: './tsconfig.json'> which doesnt work. But this solution works.

Comment: I added the project to my default file and ESLINT works in my next.js app. Incredible this isn't added by default. No tutorial even mentioned it either!

Comment: thanks man sorted me right out. error prompt should suggest this ffs

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone outhere using `.eslintrc.yml` can use following to fix above issue

```
extends:
  - airbnb-typescript
parserOptions:
  project:
    - tsconfig.json
```

PS: `tsconfig.json` is in root folder, change it to match your location in case its not in root folder.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same problem as I had:
my ESLint was working perfectly fine, but my VS Code extension was throwing this error. I had to change the Extension setting and reload it in order for it to work. Basically, I did this:

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto"}],
```

[Also explained my problem and solution here](https://blog.anja-stricker.de/solving-eslint-problems)