# How to setup Webpack using Create-React-App for sass-resources-loader?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-4

I'd like to build a project with CSS modules + SASS. I'd like to have some global styles (mixins, variables, functions etc), that will be available in every component.module.scss. For that I need to import my global styles to every single module style file. As I expect to have a lot of components, I was looking for options to do this automatically. I've found **sass-resourcess-loader** ,might help with that.

However, as **I don't have any experiencies with Webpack**, I have troubles to setting it up.

What I did so far:

1. Created my react app with **create-react-app**
2. Installed **node-sass** and **sass-resources-loader**
3. In my **project-folder/node_modules/react-scripts/webpack.config.js** on line **595** I've added

{
test: /.scss$/,
use: [
{
loader: "style-loader",
}, {
loader: "css-loader",
}, {
loader: "sass-loader",
}, {
loader: "sass-resources-loader",
}
],
}

Sorry I cannot get that code snippet styled properly somehow. Also I've tried options field:

```
options: {
 resources: "./src/global.scss"
}
```

But nothing works, I still get undefined variable in my modular scss file.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay so I've find solution with **CRACO** (Create React App Configuration Override).

**1)** I've uninstalled sass-reasources-loader as is not needed anymore and reverted the changes in webpack.config.js

**2)** Installed [CRACO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) and [craco-sass-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-sass-resources-loader)

**3)** Created craco.config.js file inside root directory of my project and added this:

const sassResourcesLoader = require("craco-sass-resources-loader");

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
    },
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: sassResourcesLoader,
            options: {
                resources: "./src/global.scss",
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

**4)** In package.json I've changed the scripts to:

```
"start": "craco start",

"build": "craco build",
```

Now everything works. If you need more info, click on the links provided in step 2.

Comment: Anyone who is using typescript with cra can get Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser. using eslint for linting purpose. They can follow this thread for solving their error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser/64488474#64488474