# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Occurred while linting in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, storybook, typescript-eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have this really weird "*bug*" I guess you can call it with **eslint** when I try and run `yarn lint`

```
$ tsc --noEmit && eslint src/**/*.ts{,x}
```

For some reason it fails with

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.32.0

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Occurred while linting /Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/src/hooks/useFirebase.ts:13
    at ExpressionStatement (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint-plugin-storybook/lib/rules/prefer-csf.js:18:44)
    at /Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/safe-emitter.js:45:38)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:293:26)
    at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:322:22)
    at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/node-event-generator.js:336:14)
    at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (/Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:711:23)
    at /Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter/linter.js:960:32
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Also, if I have my **useFirebase.ts** file focused (in view) on VSCode and run `yarn start` I get the error:

```
Failed to compile

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Occurred while linting /Users/Reynaldo/Documents/cafemat/src/hooks/useFirebase.ts:13
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Yet if I put in focus (into view) any other file on VSCode and run `yarn start` the project compiles and runs without problems.

Is this a weird bug or am I doing something wrong? Here are the files:

`useFirebase.ts`

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { FirebaseApp, deleteApp, getApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { appName, firebaseConfig } from "../config/firebaseConfig";

function useFirebase(): FirebaseApp | null {
  const [firebaseApp, setFirebaseApp] = useState<FirebaseApp | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let app: FirebaseApp;

    try {
      app = getApp(appName);
    } 
    catch (err) {
      app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, appName);
    }

    setFirebaseApp(app);

    return () => {
      deleteApp(app);
    };
  }, []);

  return firebaseApp;
}

export default useFirebase;
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "xxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "1.3.4",
    "firebase": "9.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "1.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.ts{,x}'",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint src/**/*.ts{,x}",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "serve": "serve -s build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.2",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.2",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.7",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.2",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/reach__router": "^1.3.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "cypress": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-chai-friendly": "^0.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.1.1",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

`.eslintrc`

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:cypress/recommended",
    "plugin:chai-friendly/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react", 
    "@typescript-eslint", 
    "jest", 
    "cypress", 
    "chai-friendly", 
    "storybook"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true,
    "cypress/globals": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "rules": {
    "linebreak-style": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ],
    "cypress/no-assigning-return-values": "error",
    "cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting": "error",
    "cypress/assertion-before-screenshot": "warn",
    "cypress/no-force": "warn",
    "cypress/no-async-tests": "error",
    "no-unused-expressions": 0,
    "chai-friendly/no-unused-expressions": 2,
    "storybook/prefer-csf": "error"
  }
}
```

`.eslintignore`

```
# Temporary lint ignore because storybook example files
# generated files that go against specified ESLint rules.
  src/stories
# ESLinting error taken off by ignoring config files
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser/64488474#64488474
  tailwind.config.js
  postcss.config.js
  craco.config.js
```

Comment: Reading the error, it seems that something on line 13 is undefined, yet we're trying ask it for its `name`. What's happening in `getApp`?

Comment: `getApp` is a Firebase provided function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app.md#getapp

Also when I commented it out it gives linting error for `initializeApp` as well. Its as if eslint has problems with all Firebase functions for some reason :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I solved the problem. For some reason the `prefer-csf` rule of `eslint-plugin-storybook` causes this error. Once I commented out `"storybook/prefer-csf": "error"` from the `.eslintrc` the `yarn lint` command runs without problems. If anyone has a clue as to why this solves the error it would be greatly appreciated if you could explain. Thanks! :D

Comment: Interesting. Does your code use the Storybook `storiesOf` syntax anywhere? Could you share that code in the question?

Comment: Nope, I don't use `storiesOf` syntax anywhere and if I comment out `"storybook/prefer-csf": "error"` the linter, storybook, and everything else runs completely fine. 