# How can i see all my deprecated methods functions in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i see all my deprecated methods functions in react native? i have a old react native project and its not working fine errors are coming one by one so i updated all of my packages which were outdated but after that many errors are coming too while running the project

i tired to fix some but now i get to know that my projects and many deprecated functions and it become very hard to solve one by one i do have many files in one project, So is their any easy way so see all deprecated functions methods variables etc. i do run npm outdated to see  deprecated npm packages but it was not a solution..

i dont want my code updated i just want to search or see that what functions and methods are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

[eslint-plugin-deprecation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-deprecation) lets deprecated functions and more be shown.

Install it with `npm i -D eslint-plugin-deprecation`. If not already installed, install just enough Typescript to run make this ESLint plugin work but not so much to force the whole project to use it: `npm i -D typescript@4.0 @types/jest @types/react @types/react-native @types/react-test-renderer @tsconfig/react-native`. This is a subset of the [official guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#adding-typescript-to-an-existing-project).

Create `tsconfig.json` if it doesn't exist:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json"
}
```

Replace or add to `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "plugins": ["deprecation"],
  "rules": {
    "deprecation/deprecation": "warn",
  },
};
```

Create [`.eslintignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66260842/10477326):

```
.eslintrc.js
```

As an example, add and use a deprecated function in a newly created project's App.js:

```js
// ...
import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

/**
 * @deprecated
 */
function dontUseThis() {}

/* $FlowFixMe[missing-local-annot] The type annotation(s) required by Flow's
 * LTI update could not be added via codemod */
const Section = ({children, title}): Node => {
  dontUseThis(); // Newly added line 37 as an example of a deprecated function
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
// ...
```

Then deprecated functions will be shown when `npm run lint` is used:

```
$ npm run lint

> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 lint
> eslint .


/run/user/1000/AwesomeProject/App.js
  10:14  warning  'Node' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  37:3   warning  'dontUseThis' is deprecated.      deprecation/deprecation

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)
```

Comment: i tried this after running  npm run lint it just works but it didn't show me my deprecated functions

Comment: It might be that the deprecated functions you have aren't marked with @deprecated yet in the versions you have. Have you tried upgrading them and running the linter one version at a time?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean? i upgraded all packages which wear deprecated

Comment: I meant upgrade the packages to the last version before the deprecated functions are removed. There is one other way before I run out of ideas. You try creating a .d.ts file marking all the functions you don't want to use anymore, then do npm run lint

Comment: as i already told my all deprecated  packages are updated:)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74531058/6061721), but it didn't work until I nested the deprecation specific stuff under "overrides" in `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "plugins": ["deprecation"],
      "rules": {
        "deprecation/deprecation": "warn"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```