# Why is ESLint trying to run on its own config file when using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have `.eslintignore` right next to `eslintrc.js`

The ignore is simply this:

```
.eslintrc.js
dist/*
node_modules/*
out-tsc/*
```

However when I go into `eslintrc.js` I get this error:

```
Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/.eslintrc.js` using `parserOptions.project`: <tsconfigRootDir>/../../../../../../users/dstein/repositories/social-experiment/packages/site/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file
```

The article it links to unsurprisingly says to use `.eslintignore` if you don't want to lint the file the error is on. Meanwhile, my TS config does not say to include any `js` files.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
}
```

Really bewildered why TS Config saying to only include `ts` files would have ESLint it was configured to run using `parserOptions.project`

The ESLint config is fairly straightforward (I will remove all the rules to save some reading here):

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  extends: [
    '@open-wc',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'prettier',
  ],
  rules: {},
};
```

Comment: Haha, I am just facing the exact same problem.

Comment: The solution is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser

Comment: You need to declare the parserOptions only for ts files.

Comment: @wasserholz I don't understand. My parserOptions points to `tsconfig.json` and that config says to only use `.ts` files?

Comment: you also need to declare that for .eslintrc.js like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488474/4541731

Answer (score 0):

Add your eslint config file to the list of files to be ignored in the config itself.

Something like this:

```
ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.js', 'postcss.config.js'],
```