# Cypress custom plugin

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am writing cypress test for my react application and one of the cypress test is to click on a button to download then it will download to a "cypress\download" folder. I wanted to delete the download folder after each cypress test.

**cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
const {rmdir} = require('fs')
module.exports = (on,config) => {
    on('task', {
        deleteFolder(folderName){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                rmdir(folderName, {recursive: true}, (err) =>{
                    if(err){
                        return reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(null)
                });
            });
        }
    });     
}
```

I wanted to git commit my cypress test file, but encountered the below error.

> Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been for @typescript-eslint/parser.
>
> The file doe snot match your project config: cypress\plugins\index.js
>
> The file must be included in at least one of the project provided

What do I have to add in the "parserOptions.project" to include the cypress plugin?

Comment: have you tried this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to add in the "parserOptions.project" to include the cypress plugin?

In your ESLint configuration file. See https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting.

Example:

```js
// eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: true,
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  // ...
}
```

@xxestter's linked ["parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510287/parseroptions-project-has-been-set-for-typescript-eslint-parser) contains the right info.